# typings for chrome window api extention window.performance.memory

Tags: google-chrome, typescript

How do I get a handle on window.performance.memory in typescript? Is there a definition for the non standard api stuff?

Thanks

Comment: you can search for typings or write one. Alternatively you can cast window to any but no IntelliSense will work there.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a definition for the non standard api stuff

You can declare it yourself quite easily:

```
interface Performance{
    memory:any
}

window.performance.memory; // No error
```

## More

Lib.d.ts extensions : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/lib.d.ts.html

Comment: This is not a good answer. If using “any” then it might as well be JavaScript, not Typescript.