# Angular: how to record memory usage?

Tags: angular, memory-management

I want to record/monitor the memory usage of my angular application.

Why? Because after amount of time the application crashed because it go out of memory.

Of course i know there is a memory leak, but its not the question how to solve it right now.

What i try to do: Add a setInterval for 20 seconds. And then print the current memory usage. For example with the command: window.performance.memory

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// interface Performance{
//   memory:any
// }

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ``,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(window.performance.memory);
    }, 20000);
  }
}
```

Expected:
Print the memory usage every 20 seconds.

In reality:
It show the error:

```
Property 'memory' does not exist on type 'Performance'
```

Tried:
Adding an interface called performance, like in the code above.
copied from:
[typings for chrome window api extention window.performance.memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45049137/typings-for-chrome-window-api-extention-window-performance-memory)

The typescript error still exist.

The question:
How to execute: window.performance.memory inside setInterval in angular?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you think this would better received than [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096591/deletedddddddddddddddd)? What exactly does *"Angular not recognize 'memory'"* mean - are you talking about a TypeScript error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because i added more details about the question. Yes, of course typescript error. You can type window.performance.memory in the devtools console and it will show you the memory usage. Now type it no matter where in your angular application, it will produce typescript error, so it wont compile your code.

Comment: *"Yes, of course typescript error"* - then **show that** in your question. Give a [mre] with correct formatting. Did you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45049137/3001761?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33155
it not possible to access to memory property because its not standard API.

So the solution I came to is to use console.memory:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(console.memory);
}, 20000);
```